# Entered details in registration page are getting cleared when user navigates to Edit cart page from order review page

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout

When iam trying to purchase a product in magento frontend shopping cart as a guest / register user. after entering the details in billing information, shipping information, shipping method, payment information. later in order review form I pressed Edit cart link then goes to add another product in to my cart. then the data entered in billing, shipping information is missed, need to re-enter the data.

I want to maintain these data in session, so that no need to re enter the data.

can you please help me out ASAP...

thanks in advance...

Comment: Is there some custom checkout module or module related to shopping cart? Are you using onepage checkout?

Comment: yes I am using one page checkout process. When not logged in user want to purchase a product as a guest or  register.